# When the Graphics instance is created

Tags: java, graphics, paint, repaintmanager

I know that when `paint` is happening an instance of the `Graphics` class should be created. That `Graphics` object (Actually `Graphics2D` object) is going through `paint()` method and all the details that should be printed or updated on the screen are stored in that object.

As I know of this process is handled by `RepaintManager` when user called `repaint()` method or when repaint is needed to the `UI`. So, a `Graphics` instance has to be created to store the information regarding the painting.

As this process is handled by `RepaintManager`, I thought that the `Graphics` instance is also initialized inside `RepaintManager`. But I found source code of `RepaintManager` recently. And couldn't find a place that a new `Graphics` instance is created.

So, is it really created inside `RepaintMananger` or anywhere else..?

Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's created in Component.getGraphics() see the [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#getGraphics--) for more information

Comment: Thanks.. I thought it is there to be used by programmers to edits the component's graphics. I didn't know that it is used by `RepaintManager` also..